# Hibernate composite class mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I have a problem with hibernate mapping for composite class.
The problem is that I have 2 classes which is bounded for 2 tables, Also I have third class (Basket) which can contain diffrent class types.

```
abstract class Fruit {...}
@Entity
@Table
class Apple extends Fruit {...}

@Entity
@Table
class Orange extends Fruit{...}

@Entity
@Table
class Basket {

 ...

 @Column
 private FruitType fruit_type;

 // I dont know how to map composite class here
 // It has to be mapped for two tables simultaneously 
 // which table has to be bound, depends on field fruit_type
 private Fruit fruit;
```

...
}

Answer (score 0):

Use [JPA inheritance](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance).

The `fruit_type` does not need to be explicitly mapped in `Basket` (if it is not needed). It should be relevant for `Fruit` class (which can be annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`) where you specify it as `@DiscriminatorColumn`. The in each of the `Apple` and `Orange` just define specific `@DiscriminatorValue`. It can be also an `enum` if you like.